# swichMap& combineLatest behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Component template:

```html
<div *ngIf="isAdditionalInfoAvailable$ | async">section 1</div>
<div *ngIf="isAdditionalInfoAvailable$ | async">section 2</div>
```

Component ts code:

```js
readonly sessionInfo$ = new BehaviourSubject<SessionInfo | null>(null);

readonly files$ = this.sessionInfo$.pipe(
    filter(Boolean),
    switchMap(sessionInfo =>
      this.filesApiService
        .getPublicDocuments(sessionInfo!.conferenceSessionId, { limit: this.filesPreviewLimit })
        .pipe(tap(() => console.log('request')), catchError(() => of(null)))
    )
  );

readonly isAdditionalInfoAvailable$ = combineLatest([this.sessionInfo$, this.files$]).pipe(
    filter(([sessionInfo]) => !!sessionInfo),
    map(([sessionInfo, files]) => !!sessionInfo!.description || !!files?.data?.length)
  );
```

and I see two 'request' messages in the console. Why?

Possibly combineLatest subscribes for each items in the argument when get subscription for itself.
If so I could do smth like that (share added):

```js
readonly request$ = this.filesApiService
        .getPublicDocuments(sessionInfo!.conferenceSessionId, { limit: this.filesPreviewLimit })
        .pipe(share());

readonly files$ = this.sessionInfo$.pipe(
    filter(Boolean),
    switchMap(sessionInfo => this.request$)
  );
```

but in this case I have no idea where to get `sessionInfo` in request$ in getPublicDocuments. I don't think it is fine to keep it as component class field.
Also I cannot use function because it returns new `Observable`.

Could you please describe how to treat that case?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `shareReplay(1)` operator in the end of `files$` pipe

```
readonly files$ = this.sessionInfo$.pipe(
    filter(Boolean),
    switchMap(sessionInfo =>
      this.filesApiService
        .getPublicDocuments(sessionInfo!.conferenceSessionId, { limit: this.filesPreviewLimit })
        .pipe(tap(() => console.log('request')), catchError(() => of(null)))
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

when `sessionInfo$` changed it rewrite cached value on new one. Don't forget about unsubscribing.

Don't worry about keeping storageInfo as component field. You can make it private and readonly and that will help you just to store your object. Also, you can make it ReplaySibject and then you don't have to set initial value. In that case your observables will tick only when in storageInfo will be any proper value

You can also make the parent tag `<ng-content>` with convertion to type you need but this creates extra field in component class

Comment: Do note that using shareReplay is kind of dangerous and in this specific case, it'll probably create a memory leak as it'll never been unsubscribed from. See doc to understand why: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/shareReplay#reference-counting it's usually a better idea to use the config object and in this case pass the `bufferSize` as `1` and `refCount` as `true`

Comment: @maxime1992 I understand that this is could be reason for memory leak. This is havent been in question but canceling subscription is the concrete programmer approach

Comment: @maxime1992 another big thing about your suggestion about `refCount` is that if some subscriber unsubscribes the subscription will store the latest value. And when some new subscriber will appear subscription will take him latest value without reloading the pipe

Answer (score 0):

You're getting two 'request' in console because each `async` pipe triggers a separate subscription. So the observable is subscribed twice.

`combineLatest` by itself would only trigger one subscription externally.

Quick workaround is to wrap the `*ngIf` condition in a outer container using an object and reuse it's value. Without wrapping it in an object, the condition would fail when the observable emits false and the `<div>`s within the `async` would never be checked.

```html
<ng-container
  *ngIf="{
    value: (isAdditionalInfoAvailable$ | async)
  } as isAdditionalInfoAvailable"
>
  <div *ngIf="isAdditionalInfoAvailable.value">section 1</div>
  <div *ngIf="isAdditionalInfoAvailable.value">section 2</div>
</ng-container>
```